# ReactJS with useSWR hook, passing params to mutate() issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm having trouble passing additional parameters to `fetcher()` with `useSWR()` hook. In below code, on click of `handleRetrieveVersion` I would expect additionalData to be populated with `{arg: { pathParam: "this should be passed to fetcher" }}` but all I'm getting is `undefined`. I'm trying to follow example from https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation#bound-mutate. Would appreciate any help with this.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import useSWR from "swr";

  const fetcher = async (
    [url]: [string],
    additionalData: {
      arg: {
        pathParam?: string;
        body?: unknown;
      };
    }
  ): Promise<any> => {
    // additionalData should be "this should be passed to fetcher"
    console.log("additionalData", additionalData);
    return "whatever";
  };


const SomeComponent = (): JSX.Element => {

  const { data, error, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR(["somekey"], fetcher);

  const handleRetrieveVersion = () => {
    mutate({
      additionalData: {
        arg: { pathParam: "this should be passed to fetcher" },
      },
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleRetrieveVersion}>handleRetrieveVersion</Button>
    </>
  );
};

 

export default SomeComponent;
```